# update statement with dynamically changing rows using prepared statement

Tags: java, sql

I am planning to execute an update statement using a prepared statement that makes use of a dynamically changing number of columns. for eg: in the first update statement I update only name and age of a table. in the second instance, I update age, city, state, country..etc. in the next instance, I update 150 columns like this.

can someone provide me what is the perfect approach for this in java?
following is the example

If the user provides input for name and age then I update
`UPDATE table1 set name = <> ,age = <>;`

If the user provides input for `city` `name` `state` `country` and `pin` then the update statement should be like this-

`UPDATE table1 set name = <>, city = <>,state= <>,country=<>, pin = <>;`

Comment: You will not be able to use a single prepared statement for this. Build the SQL dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Build your sql query like this

```
  update demotable set col1 = case when @col1 is null then col1 else @col1 end
```

OR

Here @col is passed as value from front end.

from which you may create dynamic sql

```
  declare @col1 nvarchar(max)  /// from front you can pass your column value with its column name like: col1 = 'col1'

  declare @Query = 'update demotable set = ' + @col1   /// it create query as  update demotable set col1 = 'col1'

  PREPARE stmt1 FROM @Query ; 
  EXECUTE stmt1
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

I am new to MYSQL but this logic will surely work.

Comment: I have 200 columns to update. in different update statements i update the different columns..not sure how your sql query works. can you elaborate please

Comment: it depends how you are passing your input to the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can write one statement like this:

```
UPDATE table1
    SET name = COALESCE(?, name),
        age = COALESCE(?, age),
        city = COALESCE(?, city),
        . . .
```

Notes:

- This assumes that the values are not being set to `NULL`.
- The `?` is a placeholder for a *parameter*.  Don't munge query strings with user input.
- Presumably you want a `WHERE` clause to limit what rows get updated.

Comment: I cannot use COALESCE, - as per the requirement, if name tag present in xml and value not present, we have to update with NULL. if name tag itslef not present in xml then we should leave the field as it is no update for that field.